# Why do HTML dropdown selections sent in the form of an email look so unreadable

Tags: html, forms

I'm working on an automated shopping list using HTML only. I've figured out a way to send the dropdown selections to an email draft. I wanted to know why the HTML dropdown selections look bad once they reach the email draft.
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the dropdown selections made are stored in a non-plaintext form. That is, the special characters like the `+`,  `&` make it look really unreadable. How do you change that?
So instead of flour brand = Option A, or something like that, it says `flour+brand=OptionA`
And instead of separating flour brand and weight with a comma or a newline, it says `flour+brand=OptionA&flour+weight=5kg` or something like that.
How do I make the draft more readable by getting rid of unnecessary characters, etc.?

I'm really sorry, but honestly, I don't know any other way of expressing myself. I hope the screenshot helps. I'd highly appreciate an edit for this question's title and stuff.
If possible, do help out.

**Code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Automated Shopping List</h1>
        <form action="mailto:recipient@gmail.com" method="post">
            <label for="flour brand">Flour Brands:</label>
            <select name="flour brand" id="flour">
                <option value="OptionA">OptionA</option>
                <option value="OptionB">OptionB</option>
                <option value="OptionC">OptionC</option>
            </select>
            <select name="flour weight" id="flour">
                <option value="1kg">1kg</option>
                <option value="2kg">2kg</option>
                <option value="3kg">3kg</option>
                <option value="4kg">4kg</option>
                <option value="5kg">5kg</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label for="sugar weight">Sugar Weight:</label>
            <select name="sugar weight" id="sugar">
                <option value="1kg">1kg</option>
                <option value="2kg">2kg</option>
                <option value="3kg">3kg</option>
                <option value="4kg">4kg</option>
                <option value="5kg">5kg</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more details? It seems like that you want to show the selected items form some dropdowns in an email, right? Something like this: `Flour Brand: OptionA, Flour Weight: 5kg, Sugar Weight: 2kg`?

Comment: Yes, but I got that part. I sent the HTML dropdown selections from the webpage to an email draft. But once the selections reach the form of an email draft, they become unreadable because of those special characters like the +,=,& How do I get rid of those special characters and get the selections in a plaintext email draft? Like without those characters?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to get the selections in the form that you just edited

Comment: Thx so much! Another quick question, what if were to put both weight and brand of flour on the same line. For example, right now it says flour brand=OptionB
flour weight=1kg one line after the other. How do I get it to display as flour brand=OptionB, weight = 1kg? LIke both on the same line. If I need to create a new question for this please suggest a suitable title

Comment: You're welcome. The text you see is the result of the POST method and you have not so much control over it, because it's used for sending data, not displaying it. If you want to have a "pretty" email, then you need to create a custom function for that, which is fired on form "submit".

Comment: Something like this: `<form action="a function that receives the form data, creates a beautiful HTML code from it, and then puts it into mailto:recipient@gmail.com">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244742/discussion-between-night-falcon-x-and-shahriar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding your form as plain text:

```html
<form action="mailto:recipient@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp